# Setting specific body class in Magento based on category parent

Tags: php, xml, magento

Via the layout.xml I am trying to add a body class for a specific category like :

```
<CATEGORY_123>
<reference name="root">
<action method="addBodyClass"><className>foo</className></action>
</reference>
</CATEGORY_123>
```

This works when I am on the page for that category id (123) but not for any of the children of that category.  To be sure I am checking on a child of the parent I want I plugged this into my header :

```
<?php 
$catID= '';
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if($category){
    $path = $category->getPath();
    $aCatIds = explode('/',$path);
    $iCatID = $aCatIds[2]; // get the third level category = parent
    echo $iCatID;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the reason for this after finding this blog post :  http://www.eddiemay.me.uk/2011/11/07/magento-changing-the-body-class-by-category/

Seems that I also have to configure the categories in the admin to make sure they are using the Parent Category Settings :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the controller file
**Mage_Catalog_CategoryController** action 
**viewAction**
there are is an update in line **134**

```
$update->addHandle('CATEGORY_' . $category->getId());
```

and there is also addBodyClass method called (line **153**):

```
$root->addBodyClass('categorypath-' . $category->getUrlPath())
                    ->addBodyClass('category-' . $category->getUrlKey());
```

Based on those 2 code lines above, your XML update should work (I've used it in few projects myself).
You may need to check if any of the custom modules rewrites **CategoryController.php** and **viewAction**.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Good thought, I did find some rewrites but those mods were disabled.  I think this comes down to me misunderstanding what this does.. I thought it would work for all children of that cat id but it seems it only works on the page for the parent.  I will update my question to explain this.